# Can't install guest additions to virtualbox - An unauthorized request

Tags: arch-linux, virtualbox

I installed a new virtual machine yesterday. Previously, I download the guest addition iso from https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/, from within virtual box.

And then mount the iso and run the `VBoxLinuxGuestAdditions.run`, but from yesterday, I can't access this site.

Secondly (Virtualbox 6+ onwards), I can't install the guest additions from the *Insert Guest Additions CD Image* under the *Devices* tab.

But nevertheless, I tried once more, and I get:

> The network operation failed with the following error:  During network
>   request: Wrong SSL certificate format.

I need to test a software with the guest addition.

I am on Arch Linux and the **VirtualBox** version is **6.0.6 r129722**.

What's wrong with VirtualBox?

Is there an alternative way to download the guest additions?

Comment: What is the host OS?, What is the guest?

Comment: It's added - I am using Arch Linux and the VirtualBox Version is 6.0.6 r129722

Comment: And what is the guest OS?

Comment: I have installed Linux Mint. Same goes for every other GNU/Linux and BSDs I have tried! The second problem is persistent - you can't install the CD images from the Insert Guest Additions CD Image under the Devices tab from virtualbox 6.0 onwards; so I have to look at the alternative way - downloading and mounting the iso. Which can't be done now, the site shows ``An unauthorized request".

Comment: The guest additions ISO can be downloaded without https from [this folder](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.0.6/) [here](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.0.6/VBoxGuestAdditions_6.0.6.iso).

Comment: Then it must be something wrong here. May be it's personal problem:
https://imgur.com/a/XLaKChw

Comment: Are you somehow redirected to https?

Comment: Yes, that's true. I can't simply strip https on firefox. I have also tried chromium browser - which shows "This server could not prove that it is download.virtualbox.org; its security certificate is from download.oracle.com. This may be caused by a misconfiguration or an attacker intercepting your connection."

Comment: I can download http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.0.6/VBoxGuestAdditions_6.0.6.iso from `links` browser or I can use wget.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: On chromium, I clicked advanced button. It showed that it is a oracle certificate, so I can click override (I think this is secure, `http` is definitely not secure).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the comments:

The current version 6.0.6 of the guest additions iso can be downloaded from <strike>http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.0.6/VBoxGuestAdditions_6.0.6.iso</strike>
https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.0.6/VBoxGuestAdditions_6.0.6.iso
(**Edit:** https works again)

But get the hash from the `https` site, https://www.virtualbox.org/download/hashes/6.0.6/MD5SUMS and check it.

Comment: If downloaded using `http`, someone can substitute the code for other code, and do  damage, or steal data.

Comment: [md5sum](https://www.virtualbox.org/download/hashes/6.0.6/MD5SUMS) f7c63c2ffebc5d7ff950435d41abbfdf VBoxGuestAdditions_6.0.6.iso

Comment: Yes but only because that hash can be got via `https`.

Comment: This method works for version 7.0.4 (just replace 6.0.6 with 7.0.4 everywhere in the URL).

Answer (score 3):

Since you have already  installed Virtual Box version 6.0.8 on Arch linux, and have the error message below with Guest Additions :

"The network operation failed with the following error:
  During network request: Unknow reason."

Try to install a extra package (virtualbox-guest-iso) to solve the error massage above:

pacman -S virtualbox-guest-iso

Comment: Virtualbox says it still cannot find the file after installing that package, and wants to donload it.